# How to make adjust the line color opacity in turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want to adjust the opacity of the lines drawn by the pen in turtle to 50% but can't seem to find any solution. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322465/python-turtle-opacity) shows no solutions.

It seems like we can't use rgba as the color choice in this library? If so, any library that is recommended to use?

```
import turtle


t = turtle.Turtle()
s = turtle.Screen()
s.bgcolor('black')
t.pencolor('white')
t.speed('fastest')
t.pensize(5)


for i in range (100):
    t.forward(500)
    t.left(125)

turtle.done()
```

[image: wish to change the opacity of the lines drawn]

Answer (score 0):

You can convert RGBA values to RGB using Certain [Formulae](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2049362/13656598). There is  a [simplified version of this formula](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/113050) if the background is white

My code:

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
s = turtle.Screen()

bg = (0,0,0)

s.bgcolor(bg)
t.pencolor('white')
t.speed('fastest')
t.pensize(3)

fg = (0 / 255, 255 / 255, 0 / 255, 100 / 255)

r = max(min(((1 - fg[3]) * bg[0]) + (fg[3] * fg[0]), 1), 0)
g = max(min(((1 - fg[3]) * bg[1]) + (fg[3] * fg[1]), 1), 0)
b = max(min(((1 - fg[3]) * bg[2]) + (fg[3] * fg[2]), 1), 0)

for i in range (75):
    t.pencolor(r,g,b) 
    t.forward(500)
    t.left(125)

turtle.done()
```

Comment: it doesnt seem to work for me, i.e. I cannot make the foreground color is semi transparent relative to any of the background color. Mind to show how? i.e. semi transparent green foreground vs black background?

Comment: If you are using non-black or non-white backgrounds, you need to use a more complex formula [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2049362/13656598). I have changed my answer to reflect this

Comment: i cant seem to use other rgb values as bg, for bg = (172, 52, 52), theres error risen up: it gives bad color sequence: (172, 52, 52). 
Also, how would this solution work for non-solid color background, i.e. an image?

Comment: ok, I need to change bg to  (172/255, 52/255, 52/255) to make it work. If I want opacity 50%, does that mean i need to input 255*0.5 /255 as 'a' value?

Comment: **If I want opacity 50%, does that mean i need to input 255*0.5 /255 as 'a' value** Yup.
You can also use 50 / 100, if you prefer percentages